# How to use a Windows share mapped using `net use \\host\share`?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

> How to use a Windows share mapped using `net use \\host\share`?

I've accidentally forgotten to include the device name, e.g. `Z:`, in the above command, resulting in the share being mapped without a corresponding network drive showing up in Windows Explorer. The mapped share is listed using `net use`.

Now, what can a mapped share, without a corresponding network drive, be used to? Is it possible to link the share to a network drive afterwards (how)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> resulting in the share being mapped without a corresponding network drive showing up

Technically, if a drive letter wasn't specified, then the share isn't *mapped;* it's only connected to.

> Now, what can a mapped share, without a corresponding network drive, be used to?

Everything, because most programs **accept UNC paths directly** – mapping to a drive letter is optional. For example, you can open the path `\\host\share` in Explorer or Notepad or Word or any other program; you can even `dir` it from the Command Prompt. This has been possible ever since Windows 95 – for more than 20 years now.

Windows will automatically connect to shares whenever an UNC path is used, so technically you don't even need `net use` at all. However the command remains useful even without specifying drive letters, because it lets you specify a custom username and password.

That said, there *are* still valid reasons to use drive letter mappings: they let you quickly see used/free space in "This PC" ("My Computer"), they're shorter to type, and you can actually `cd` into them via Command Prompt.

> Is it possible to link the share to a network drive afterwards (how)?

If you still want to map the share to a drive, simply repeat the command *with* a drive letter:

```
net use z: \\host\share
```

Comment: Thank you - so using `net use  \\host\share` is only useful to establish a connection with a custom username and password? Given that such connection has been established, then Windows will automatically use it when needed from e.g. Explorer?

Comment: Yes, it will be used automatically.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to link the share to a network drive afterwards?

Yes, using these commands:

```
net use \\host\share /delete
net use \\host\share z:
```

This deletes the mapping and then recreates it using the drive letter you specify.

Comment: Thank you - but I know this. I want to know, what the mapped share can be used to, not just deleted and remapped with a corresponding device name :)

Comment: @Shuzheng I'd have to do some research to answer the other part of your question. If you didn't mean to ask the part I answered, please edit your question to clarify.